# Missing plenty of parameters in VS2015 project properties window

Tags: properties, visual-studio-2015

I was updating project properties in VS2015 (like preprocessor, folders, etc) by right-clicking on the project, then project properties. But since a day or 2, the project window is missing almost all entries:
[image]
How can I recover missing entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fount it, I actually changed the language of VS2015 after creating the projects. Reverting back to previous language makes it work again.